# Why am I able to display an entire JSON object, but not get a value from inside it?

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have Vue single-file component which displays a product's details (well its meant to anyway). All my data seems to be loading fine from a Vuex store. This is my `Product.vue` page:

```
<template>
   <div class="page-content">
      {{Product}}               <!-- this works and shows JSON on the page -->
      {{Product.ProductTitle}}  <!-- this shows nothing at all -->
   </div>
</template>
<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
    export default {
        name: "Product",
        computed:
            {
                ...mapGetters({
                    Product: 'getProduct',
                })
            },
        serverPrefetch() {
            return this.getProduct();
        },
        mounted() {
            if (!this.Product.length) {
                this.getProduct();
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getProduct() {
                return this.$store.dispatch('loadProduct', {ProductID: this.$route.params.ProductID})
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The data in the computed `Product` variable is just this:

```
[ { "ProductID": 12552, "ProductTypeID": 1, "ProductStatusID": 3, "ProductTitle": "Sony PlayStation 4 Pro" }]
```

I cannot fathom out why `{{Product}}` displays the whole JSON object, but `{{Product.ProductTitle}}` shows nothing?

UPDATE: [JSFiddle showing problem](https://jsfiddle.net/zvfo1n7a/)

Comment: In your fiddle example, the `product` variable is a list of lists. If you do `{{Product[0][0].ProductTitle}}` it works.

Comment: @drec4s what do you mean by a list of lists? it seems to be the way it comes out of the database

Comment: It has double brackets after the variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object inside array inside array e.g.: [[{}]] so you have to get the data like this:  `{{Product[0][0].ProductTitle}}`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    Product: [
      [{
        "ProductID": 14896,
        "ProductStatusID": 3,
        "CountryID": 207,
        "ProductTitle": "PS4 Pro Console +  Call of Duty: Modern Warfare / Death Stranding + Metro Exodus",
        "ProductItemDescription": "<p>The best PS4 Pro bundle offer!</p>"
      }]
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h1 {
  color: black
}

h2 {
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <article role="article" class="">
    <h1>
      {{Product[0][0].ProductTitle}}
      <!-- this doesn't work? -->
    </h1>
    <h2>
      {{Product}}
    </h2>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, I get an error then saying `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProductTitle' of undefined"`

Comment: It is probably because Vue tries to render it before product array is loaded. Check if Product[0] exists first e.g. `{{Product[0] && Product[0].ProductTitle}}`

Comment: If I do `{{Product[0]}}` it works fine and shows the JSON. If I do `{{Product[0].ProductTitle}}` then I get an error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProductTitle' of undefined"`

Comment: This is strange, can you post here a bit more code?  Create snippet may be

Comment: JSFiddle done showing the problem https://jsfiddle.net/zvfo1n7a/

Comment: Is there any docs to explain how to access lists/arrays in this way?

Comment: Well, it is part of JS language, this is how it works you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: There is something really odd going on. On the JSFiddle, your answer is correct and works. But in my application it only works if I do this `<div v-for="Item in Product" :key="Item.ProductID" >{{Item.ProductTitle}}</div>`. If I do `{{Product[0]}}` then I get the full JSON object data as expected, but if I then do `{{Product[0].ProductTitle}}` or `{{Product[0][0].ProductTitle}}' then I get Typeerrors of undefined. I can't figure this out at all :(

Comment: Try to change your fiddle to be as close to real solution as possible, then we can see it